# Generate random numbers between 1-100 and stop when it hits 99 and count the amount of attepmts it took

Tags: php, loops

Im currently working on something that i really need help with. Im gonna make a while or do while loop that with the rand fuction generates random numbers between 1 and 100. When the random numbers hits 99 the loop should stop and the show the amount of attempts it took to hit the number 99 like this:

"It took 53 attempts to hit the number 99"

If someone could help me with a simple solution I would be so grateful!

Comment: simple solution mean what do you say?

Comment: Well I would say that someone who knows how to use the rand function to generate random numbers with a set min and max number (1,100) and then make something that count the attempts it take for it to hit 99 would consider it being a simple task. For me tho I cant figure out how to do it :P

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to count how many times the loop is going untill it stops when the number hits 99.

Comment: I did try some with rand, to generate a number between min (1) and max (100). What I cant figure out is how to make it stop when it would hit the number 99, maybe with a "if" statement? And also to show how many times the loop run before it ended and hit 99.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Give a [mcve] that shows where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: For future questions, please try and provide some code. However, I believe you are looking to use a [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement, in combination with a conditional `if` statement. Hope this helps and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop like this ought to do what you are after

```
$count=0;
$i=0;
$target=99;

while( $i!=$target ){
    $i=rand(1,100);
    $count++;
}
printf('it took %u attempts to reach %u',$count,$target);
```

Comment: Gonna try it right now! thanks

Comment: It works! Thankyou so much, what i didnt have in my own code was the count part

Comment: quick question tho, how is the %u in the string generating the results? not familiar with that typing.

Comment: if you look up `sprintf` in the php manual you should see an explanation for the various letters you can use - it is essentially a placeholder for a particular type of variable - in this case as an integer which is what the value of `$count` is. Any placeholder in the string is replaced by the corresponding variable supplied as an argument to `printf`

Answer (score 1):

A [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop is fine for this;

```
for ($count = 1; rand(1, 100) != 99; $count++);
echo "It took {$count} attempts to hit the number 99";
```

Example output;

```
It took 47 attempts to hit the number 99
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I declare flag variable have value true. While loop will continue and add push value in $arrRandNum, until random value is 99.

Once 99 generates it sets flag value as false and loop will terminate.

```
<?php
    $flag = true;
    $randNum;
    $arrRandNum = array();
    while($flag){

        $randNum = rand(1,100);
        if(99 !== $randNum){
            array_push($arrRandNum,$randNum);
        }else{
            $flag = false;
        }
    }
    print_r("total attempts: ".count($arrRandNum)."<br/>");
    print_r($arrRandNum);
?>
```